# GDAL OGR API GeoJSON from other datasource as string NOT file

Tags: gdal, geojson, ogr, api

Using the GDAL/OGR API, I need to be able to convert various types of GDAL datasources into GeoJSON.  However, I do not want to write the GeoJSON to a file, but rather I need to just return the text string within the application.

For example, if I have a set of shapefiles, I want to be able to extract the data from one of these shapefiles as a GeoJSON text string.

I want to avoid the slow I/O penalty of writing it to a file and then reading the file and then deleting the file.  Such I/O would likely slow things down too much, as I would be running such tasks very frequently (if I can ever get it to work).

Is there some way to get GDAL data as GeoJSON text without writing it to a file first?

Note that I'm using the C API for GDAL/OGR within an application.  So a C or C++ solution would be preferred.  However, I'm also open to other suggestions which may give me other ideas.

**PS** .  This is on iOS.

Comment: Write to memory perhaps? i.e. output to the virtual memory filesystem /vsimem/blahblah.json, then read with VSIFOpenL VSIFReadL

Comment: `OGRGeometry::exportToJson`  will give you the json for the geometry object.

Comment: Virtual memory file system may be a possibility.   I'm not familiar with this, so will have to investigate if I can do this on iOS - unlikely, I suspect, due to sandboxing.

Comment: I think @NathanW may have the best idea.  For plain C I would use `OGR_G_ExportToJson()` .  So long as I don't need non-spatial attributes this should work:  Determine all features within the required envelope, run `OGR_G_ExportToJson()` on the geometries for each of the features, adding results to an array, and finally join all array elements into a single GeoJSON string.  I will have to experiment with this and see how it goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the suggestion from @NathanW I'm going to use `OGR_G_ExportToJson()` for each geometry in the layer (filtered by spatial extent).  I don't think I need non-spatial attributes for this, but if I do, I could theoretically build up JSON `properties` to include alongside the geometry.  So my plan is to do it this way:

1. Set a spatial filter on the layer with `OGR_L_SetSpatialFilterRect()`
2. Cycle through the filtered features with `OGR_L_GetNextFeature()`
3. Get the geometry of each feature with `OGR_F_GetGeometryRef()`
4. Get GeoJSON string of each geometry with `OGR_G_ExportToJson()`
5. Construct a GeoJSON feature string for each geometry based on a template string, including the GeoJSON geometry string obtained earlier, and add it to an array of GeoJSON feature strings
6. Construct a full GeoJSON string for a feature collection, including converting the array to a GeoJSON feature list

I've implemented most of this now, but haven't actually tested it properly yet.

Comment: If you could upload what you have in a Gist or post it here, that'd be super helpful!